# Create a list of objects

Tags: python, list, class

I am working on a little text base resultant game, but I am having troubling creating this list of `Food`, I want to put all my `Food` (either Burger, or Hotdog) in `listOfFood`. In my example I only included two, but they are all "base" on food.

Later then I will iterate through my `listOfFood` to do something. I abstracted my code to ask question (because it has too many lines, and the other information is not related to it).

```
class Food():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Food'

class HotDog(Food):
    def __init__(self):
        Food.__init__(self)

class Burger(Food):
    def __init__(self):
        Food.__init__(self)

def createFoodList(myOrders):
    # A list that contain all the food (either Burger or Hotdog)
    listOfFood = []

    # Depend what is the type of the food, create that many food object
    # and then append it to the list of food
    if myOrders[0][0] == 'HotDog':
        for number in myOrder[0][1]:
            listOfFood.append(HotDot())
    if myOrders[0][1] == 'Burger':
        for number in myOrder[0][1]:
            listOfFood.append(Burger())

    return listOfFood


todayOrders = [['HotDog', 10], ['Burger', 5]]
print(createFoodList(todayOrders))
```

I wonder if I can use list comprehension or similar method to make my `createFoodList` function better? Because my idea is to have many different kind of `Food`, so if I can return this list of food, base on `todayOrders` list `['type of food', count]` and return `[food, food, food.. ]`. The way I am doing right now is really complicated and long (I have a feeling this is not the right way).

Thank you very much.

**Edit:** Besides the list comprehension, what can I do to replace the if statements in `createFoodList`? It is decide on the `[[food, count], [food, count]..]`, and I create that food and append it to my list.

Comment: BTW why do you create an instance of `Food` for every order? As far as I can see all of your hamburgers are all the same. If they really are, you can create an instance once and reuse it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foodmap = {'HotDog': HotDog, 'Burger': Burger}

print [foodmap[f]() for (f, c) in todayOrders for x in range(c)]
```

`foodmap[f]` evaluates to either `HotDog` or `Burger` (these are classes - not class names, the classes themselves).   Calling `someclass()` creates an instance of `soemclass` and passes no arguments when calling `someclass.__init__`.   Hence `foodmap[f]()` combines both of these - it looks up the class in `foodmap` and uses the class to create an instance of that class.

Comment: Can you explain this solution a little bit to me? I am not sure how this access the `todayOrders[[]..]` Like if I know the structure of the list, `[[food, count], [food, count]... ]`.

Comment: I took a look at the list comprehension page again, I think I know that part now, just the `foodmap[f]()` needs some clarification. When `foodmap[f]` return, is that an object? Since I don't think that is a string. Thank you Ignacio.

Comment: `foodmap` is a mapping of string to class. Indexing it using a string returns the class, which you then call the constructor of.

Comment: You can even do without `foodmap` if each of your food classes has a `name` string (and it should anyway). `[food() for food in [HotDog, Burger,..] for order_name, qty in todayOrders for _ in range(qty) if food.name == order_name]`. But this is definitely too long.

Comment: impressive implementation... but it gets quite confusing D: Thank you very much @9000

Answer (score 2):

This looks more like a factory pattern. You can try the following solution

```
>>> class Food():
    def __init__(self,name='Food'):
        self.name = name
    def __repr__(self):
    return self.name

>>> class HotDog(Food):
    def __init__(self):
        Food.__init__(self,'HotDog')


>>> class Burger(Food):
    def __init__(self):
        Food.__init__(self,'Burger')

>>> def createFoodList(myOrders):
    return [apply(order[0]) for order in myOrders for i in xrange(0,order[1]) if callable(order[0])]

>>> todayOrders = [[HotDog, 10], [Burger, 5]]
>>> print(createFoodList(todayOrders))
[HotDog, HotDog, HotDog, HotDog, HotDog, HotDog, HotDog, HotDog, HotDog, HotDog, Burger, Burger, Burger, Burger, Burger]
```

Comment: Thank you for providing an alternative implementation, I learned other function `apply()`.